# libxml2 get inner (X)HTML

Tags: objective-c, ios, xhtml, libxml2

I have some sample XHTML data, like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            ..snip
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a4.1/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="contentA">
             This is sample content <b> that is bolded as well </b>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now, what I need to do, is using an `xmlNode *`, get the inner HTML of the div `contentA`. I have the `xmlNode *` for it, but how can I get the innerXML of that? I looked at content, but that only returns `This is sample content` and not the xml in the bold tags. I looked into `jQuery` for this, but due to limitations on Apple and JavaScript, I cannot use jQuery to get the innerXML of that node.

On another note, Is there another library I should be using to get the inner XML? I looked into TBXML, but that had the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content of the div node is not a single text string.  It probably consists of:

1. A text node containing `This is sample content` (with the preceding new line).
2. an element node with a tag name of `b`
3. A text node containing the trailing new line and the indentation up to the `div`'s closing tag.

The element node for the `<b>...</b>` will have the text content `that is bolded as well`.

To get all the text in the div as one string, you'll need to recursively descend through the entire tree of child nodes looking for text content.

Comment: What I need essentially is the string: `This is sample content <b> that is bolded as well </b>` that is it, nothing else is required. How can I get that string.

Comment: You still have to iterate through the nodes.  When you come to a `<b>` element, insert the text "<b>" into the strign and when you have finished with that element, insert "</b>" into the string.

Comment: I have a feeling that there might be an easier way to do this, because with that approach, need to support ordering of the properties, tags like this: <tag>This has <b>intermittent</b> bolding </tag>. Basically All I need is a the range of an XML div. How can I get that?

Comment: @Richard J. Ross III: The `<b>...</b>` is an XML element and that's that.  There's no way to get an XML parser to magically ignore parts of the XML structure.

Comment: @JeremyP : you are right! I was SURE it was not allowed in XML. You teach me something big! thx. I deleted my useless and wrong answer.

Comment: @jeremyP My solution was a modified TBXML class, which added extra fields to the TBXMLElement struct. Thank you for your help.